# Using latestOfMany() in Laravel

Tags: laravel

If I have a model called `Placement` which can have many `PlacementTqLimit` and I want to get the latest one, I'm assuming I can use this.

```
public function latestLimit()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PlacementTqLimit::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

And then add a custom attribute to get the value

```
public function getLatestLimitValueAttribute()
{
    if (empty($this->latestLimit())) {
        return '100';
    }

    return $this->latestLimit()->value;
}
```

However, when I dump the `$this->latestLimit()` I'm getting a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne`... I'm sure I shouldn't have to call `return $this->hasOne(PlacementTqLimit::class)->latestOfMany()->latest()`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->latestLimit()` will return hasOne that extend query builder.

If you want to get the latest of `PlacementTqLimit` model just use `$this->latestLimit` without `()` or you can also use `$this->latestLimit()->first()`

So, to get the latest value limit, example code is:

```
public function getLatestLimitValueAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->latestLimit) {
        return '100';
    }

    return $this->latestLimit->value;
}
```